# Why is the mantra “ Hare Krishna Hare Krishna,..Rama Hare Hare” called a Mahamantra?

Tags: krishna, mantras, iskcon

Why is this mantra called a “mahamantra”?
Is it described so only by Karshnavs/Vaishnavs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A well known Hindu scholar [**Stephen Knapp**](https://en.dharmapedia.net/wiki/Stephen_Knapp) in his book  Yoga and Meditation has provided an  answer to your question why this mantra is called as Mahamantra. There is a separate chapter called Hare Krishna Mantra in the book.

In a section of that chapter  - [**The importance of Mahamantra**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-BDODQAAQBAJ&pg=PT136&lpg=PT136&dq=hare%20rama%20mahamantra&source=bl&ots=tHwjJdrRQA&sig=ACfU3U00zz21ceg5422sn2m4fokQbvurXg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwio-PbtwavyAhVUXHwKHVFgBQsQ6AF6BQjPAhAC#v=onepage&q=hare%20rama%20mahamantra&f=false) the author  is explaining about the Hare-Krishna-Hare-krishna- HareRama-Hare-Hare mantra.Below are the excerpts.

> All mantras and all processes for self-realization are compressed into
> the  Hare krishna Maha mantra.
>
> **Narada Pancaratra.**
>
> ---
>
> These sixteen words - Hare-Krishna-Hare-krishna ,krishna krishna Hare Hare / Hare- Rama ,
> Hare- Rama  Rama Rama Hare Hare - are especially meant for
> counteracting the ill effects of the present age of quarrel and
> anxiety-
>
> **Kali-Santarana Upanishad.**
>
> ---
>
> The reason that chanting the lord's names is  such an effective  process is because lord and his
> names are identical : they are the same spiritual energy . By chanting
> Hare Krishna we are in immediate contact with god in proportion to the
> chanter's purity.

---

He also is giving refrences about this mantra   from Shreemad Bhagvatam and Chaitanya Charitamrita in the section ,citing its importance.

> कृते यद्ध्यायतो विष्णुं त्रेतायां यजतो मखै: ।
>  द्वापरे परिचर्यायां
> कलौ तद्धरिकीर्तनात् ॥ 52 ॥
>
> kṛte yad dhyāyato viṣṇuṁ tretāyāṁ yajato makhaiḥ
>  dvāpare
> paricaryāyāṁ kalau tad dhari-kīrtanāt
>
> Whatever result was obtained in Satya-yuga by meditating on Viṣṇu, in
> Tretā-yuga by performing sacrifices, and in Dvāpara-yuga by serving
> the Lord’s lotus feet can be obtained in Kali-yuga simply by chanting
> the Hare Kṛṣṇa mahā-mantra.  [**SB 12.3.52**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/3/52/)
>
> ---
>
> **Hare krishna maha-mantra is said to be the sound incarnation of krishna** and anyone who chants this mahamantra is in direct
> association with krishna and is delivered from the clutches of the
> material energy or Maya. **(Adi-lila 17.22)**

So these are some of the reasons why it is considered as maha mantra by Vaishnavas.

In summery -

- This mantra is effective espicially in this age of kali as it  reduces ill effects of the present age i.e.  quarrel and anxiety .
- All mantras and all processes for self-realization are compressed into the this mantra.
- By chanting Hare Krishna we are in immediate contact with god .

---

There are other Maha mantras also  like Om Namo Narayana  and Om Vishnave na Maha etc. , but  mainly  AFAIK this mantra is considered as Maha Mantra by some Vaishnava Sects like Gaudiya Vaishnavas (Iskcon) and Varkari sect of Maharashtra.

Comment: So, Karshnav/Gaudiya Vaishnavas deem this mantra the highest,and then only the Gayatri Mantra?

Comment: Most probably I think. Followers of  the other Vaishnava sects also chant this mantra but as you said /Gaudiya Vaishnavas consider this mantra as the supreme one and chant only this. But  considering the other example in my answer the varkarai sect. of Maharashtra a chant this mantra along  chanting the  name of "Vitthala". In general this mantra is chanted by all at the end of puja/aarati etc. but not as a maha mantra.